# Using iText7, what represent a line having negative coordinates?

Tags: pdf, location, line, itext7, negative-number

I written a `VB.Net` program that intercept `RENDER_PATH` events generated by `iText7` module.

I have written a little code to display X and Y coordinates of lines in segment.

```vb
Dim iNrPaths As Integer = 0
Dim iNrSubPaths As Integer = 0
Dim iNrSegments As Integer = 0
Dim iNrLines As Integer = 0
For Each oPath As PathRenderInfo In listener.getPaths()
    Dim m As Matrix = oPath.GetCtm()
    iNrPaths += 1
    Dim iLineWidth = oPath.GetLineWidth()
    sw.WriteLine("Render.LINE-WIDTH: " & CStr(iLineWidth))
    For Each sp As Subpath In oPath.GetPath().GetSubpaths()
        iNrSubPaths += 1
        sw.WriteLine(oPath.GetPath().ToString())
        For Each segment In sp.GetSegments()
            iNrSegments += 1
            sw.WriteLine("    " & segment.ToString())
            Select Case segment.GetType()
                Case GetType(iText.Kernel.Geom.Line)
                    iNrLines += 1
                    Dim oLine As iText.Kernel.Geom.Line = segment
                    Dim oList As List(Of Point) = oLine.GetBasePoints()
                    Dim n = 0
                    For Each p In oList
                        sw.WriteLine("      p" & CStr(n) & ".x: " & oList(n).GetX().ToString("0.####"))
                        sw.WriteLine("      p" & CStr(n) & ".y: " & oList(n).GetY().ToString("0.####"))
                        n += 1
                    Next
                    sw.WriteLine("      width: " & CStr(oList(0).GetX() - oList(1).GetX()))
                    sw.WriteLine("      height: " & CStr(oList(0).GetY() - oList(1).GetY()))
                Case GetType(iText.Kernel.Geom.BezierCurve)
                Case Else
                    Dim i0 = 0
            End Select
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Normally, the majority of lines have positives X and Y coordinates.

Example:

```
Render.LINE-WIDTH: 9,50001
iText.Kernel.Geom.Path
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Line
      p0.x: 1818,9301
      p0.y: 1475,79
      p1.x: 2365,02
      p1.y: 1475,79
      width: -546,089965820313
      height: 0
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Line
      p0.x: 2365,02
      p0.y: 1475,79
      p1.x: 2365,02
      p1.y: 2298,3989
      width: 0
      height: -822,60888671875
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Line
      p0.x: 2365,02
      p0.y: 2298,3989
      p1.x: 1818,9301
      p1.y: 2298,3989
      width: 546,089965820313
      height: 0
```

But some times, I can see NEGATIVE location values !

Example

```
Render.LINE-WIDTH: 12,5
iText.Kernel.Geom.Path
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Line
      p0.x: -99,2109
      p0.y: 8192,1396
      p1.x: -249,215
      p1.y: 8192,1396
      width: 150,004096984863
      height: 0
iText.Kernel.Geom.Path
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Line
      p0.x: 6051,98
      p0.y: 8192,1396
      p1.x: 6201,98
      p1.y: 8192,1396
      width: -150
      height: 0
iText.Kernel.Geom.Path
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Line
      p0.x: -99,2109
      p0.y: -0,0039
      p1.x: -249,215
      p1.y: -0,0039
      width: 150,004096984863
      height: 0
```

What do represent such lines ?

What is a line between 2 points having negative X and Y coordinates ?

Is there a bug/failure in my VB.Net program that is displaying theses values ?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a line between 2 points having negative X and Y coordinates ?

It's just a regular line. Why shouldn't there be negative coordinate values?

Real valued coordinate systems usually have an origin (all coordinates 0) in which all coordinate axes intersect. On each axis in one direction from the origin you have negative coordinate values and in the other diction you have positive ones.

The coordinates in the visible section of a PDF page are defined by the crop box of a page. And while it is *common* to have the origin in the lower left corner of that box and only non-negative coordinates in the crop box, this is *not required*. The origin can also be in the upper right corner, for example, with only non-positive coordinate values in the visible page.

Furthermore, a line can go from some point outside the visible area to some other point outside but nonetheless intersect the visible part.

And a third remark, you *retrieve* the CTM but you do not *apply* it to the coordinates. The CTM may also change the current coordinate system to something with unexpected coordinate values.

You might want to read up on the coordinates in PDFs in the PDF specification, ISO 32000. For starters the old part 1 should suffice: https://adobe.com/go/pdfreference